# Play framework - database create-drop issue

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm working with Play! 1.2.4 and I've come across a curious issue.

As far as I'm aware if I set the jpa.ddl in my configuration to create-drop it should drop my tables and rebuild and application restart.

```
jpa.ddl=create-drop
```

Am I right in thinking that it will only drop and create tables associated with models that have changed? I'm getting a problem where I have a model which has changed, but it isn't dropping the table. I tried to drop the table manually but it won't allow it because it `Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`. I understand this problem and to fix it I could manually drop my entire table and restart my application so it builds the tables from scratch.

My question is, is this the problem that Play! is having which is why it isn't updating that table, and if so is there a way to get around it through configuration files rather than manually dropping my table?

Thanks.

EDIT

Just for some more information, I am just assuming this is a problem and it might be something completely different but here is what I get in my logs:

```
Unsuccessful: create table Product
Table 'Product' already exists
```

I also just realised a change occuring on this load. I used to have a relationship like so

```
Product *-* Image
```

That being a ManyToMany relationship between the Product and Image table. The Image table is now not there and the relationship will be gone. However, it looks to me like the Image table isn't being deleted but the Product one is trying to be deleted and rebuilt. This might be causing the issue wit the foreign key constraint. Why wouldn't Play delete that table if its Model doesn't exist anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Runing play in dev mode?
But why don't you use jpa.ddl=update?

Answer (score 0):

Automatic schema modification with jpa is not really the best way to do. Play provides the evolutions mechanism which is more reliable because you indicate what are the changes.

In the example you give, if you delete a model class like Image, JPA does not know anything about Image class anymore so it won't delete the Image table and the Product_Image relationshop table. Thus it can't delete the Product table. JPA do not have any knowledge on what was the database before you change your model.

Evolutions are a bit more tedious to do use at start because you create evolutions files by hand but with this mechanism, your database structure is exactly what you want